# Css inline - text on the right side of an input field with button - responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am trying to make Css inline div with text on the right side of an input field with button all this has to be responsive.

I have attached an image with the layout.

This is what I have done so far.

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/register-form/" method="post">
<div style="white-space:nowrap">
<label for="id1">Send 10 Free SMS</label>
<input type="text" id="id1"/>
<input class="btn btn-green" style="background: #00c17a none repeat scroll 
0px 0px; color: #ffffff; border: 0px none; border-radius: 3px; cursor: 
pointer; margin-left: 4px; padding: 14px 40px; font-size: 20px ! important;
font-family: Roboto Condensed; font-weight: bold;" type="submit" value="FREE
TRIAL" />
</div>
</form>
```

[image: Picture of what the resulting HTML looks like - not actually spam despite looking like it]

UPDATE - question has been answer bellow - The solution was to use bootstrap .col-md-4 columns. Thank you for all help.

Comment: Be more elaborate. What is the problem you are having, and what is your question?

Comment: Please consider asking a question based on **how** to solve a programming related issue and not asking users to complete your coding challenge.

Comment: Can you provide all of your CSS please?

Comment: "This is what I have done so far. " does it work? what does your code get you? what's left?

Comment: @atmd I am using bootstrap css

Comment: @LansanaCamara I am trying to achieve the exactly design on the mockup attached in question I have done

Comment: @atmd  is missing the responsive side and the text in two line

Comment: @AndrewAshton I am using bootstrap

Comment: @beckah I wouldn't be here if I know it how solve my problem

Comment: @CabLondon that's not what saying. you are legitimately asking users to code up you mockup which is not what stack overflow is

Comment: @CabLondon After testing your html on JSFiddle, your code looks exactly like the image you provided. The only thing missing is some styling.

Comment: @LansanaCamara is not working well in responsive and also is missing the second text line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap your HTML needs to conform to its structure. This example is defining a row, which contains three equal sized columns. This tells bootstrap how to behave when the content is rendered in differing sized browsers.

```css
.advert {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  text-align: center;
}
#id1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
label {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5jsbootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline" action="/register-form/" method="post">
  <div class="container advert">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="id1" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="id1">Send 10 Free SMS<span>No Credit Card Required</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="btn btn-green" style="background: #00c17a none repeat scroll 0px 0px; color: #ffffff; border: 0px none; border-radius: 3px; cursor: pointer; padding: 14px 40px; font-size: 20px ! important;        font-family: Roboto Condensed; font-weight: bold;" type="submit" value="FREE TRIAL" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response, I really appreciate what you have done. The problem is with the two line of text  "Send 10 Free SMS " and the one bellow "No Credit Card Required"  .

Comment: And also  the elements are not inline

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some CSS, hope it helps.

Comment: Still not working :( now I got all elements in a same block

Comment: I've update my answer to include the two references you need, add them if you haven't already. Have a look at my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aa9fhm5p/

Comment: Thank you again for the effort and work you have put in . How can I remove the big gap between the elements ?